# How to import files into MSI file?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, setup-deployment

When I set the `Compression` setting in `Installshield Express` to `Uncompressed`, the build output is an `MSI` file plus lots of files and folders that the `MSI` will be using to do its installation.

How can I put all these files and folders into the `MSI` file so that it is a self-contained `MSI` package?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `Compression` to `Compressed`, and you will receive the one MSI. 
Also you can use `Release Configuration Panel` in `Release Wizard` for this purpose. There are 3 options:

- Compress all files
- Leave files uncompressed and separate from the installation package
- Custom (you can select which features should be compressed and which not)

Comment: The build output for `Installshield Express` when set to `Compressed` is an `EXE`, not an `MSI`.

Comment: Whether EXE or MSI you choose on tab `Setup.exe` in `Realease`. There is `Setup Launcher` `Yes\No` parameter. If you set `No` installshield build MSI file. It works for **Professional** and for **Premier** versions, think the same behaviuor in **Express** version.

Comment: The `Express` version does not let you choose between `EXE` or `MSI`. The only way to create an `MSI` is to use `Uncompressed`, but then there is the issue mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ok, then if you familiar with MSI - I recommend use InstEd MSI editor, whit help of it, you can change File attribute to `Compressed` and in table `Media` compress all files to internal .cab.